# Symfony2 and Doctrine: The table with name 'pim_catalog_group' already exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine, akeneo

I am trying to add an association field in an entity. When i check with

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

the mapping is shown in the list.

When trying

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

OR

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get the error

`[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
The table with name 'pim_catalog_group' already exists.`

Here is my entity code

```
Acme\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\Group:
type: entity
table: pim_catalog_group
changeTrackingPolicy: DEFERRED_EXPLICIT 
manyToOne:
    family:
        targetEntity: Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\FamilyInterface
        joinColumn:
            name: family_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: 'SET NULL'
```

I figured out it might be due to the constraints but couldn't solve it.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, the table already exist. This table could come from an association between PimCatalog and Group entities, by default the association table would then be named `pim_catalog_group` (entity1_entity2).

Comment: isn't doctrine command schema:update suppose to deal with it? i understand the error clarity but should the dropping of all constraints in associated tables and dropping pim_catalog_group manually is the right solution?

Comment: doctrine schema update will update the schema, but the problem is that the association table already exist. Manually dropping all things is not the right way, you may just override the column name, but can't say much more without more informations, you can have a look [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html)